# Display query posts at random from multiple categories

Tags: php, wordpress, while-loop

I want my WP_Query to display six posts in total from across all categories listed in the array at random.

The loop/Query I have written only displays posts from the first category (Art) in the array.

What have I got wrong?

```html
<div class="main-news">
   <!-- Define our WP Query Parameters -->
   <?php $the_query6 = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => 6, 'category_name' => 'Art' , 'Technology', 'Fashion-Beauty')); ?>

   <!-- Start our WP Query -->
   <?php while ($the_query6 -> have_posts()) {
    $the_query6 -> the_post(); ?>
    <div class="new-content">
    <!-- Display the Post Image with Hyperlink -->
     <div class="new-image"><?php the_post_thumbnail('fashion');?></div>
     <div class="new-content-excerpt">
     <!-- Display the Post Category Hyperlink -->
      <h5><?php 
      foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
      echo $category->cat_name . ' ';
      }
      ?></h5>

      <!-- Display the Post Title with Hyperlink -->
      <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
     </div>
    
    </div>
    <!-- Repeat the process and reset once it hits the limit -->
   <?php } ?>
   <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
  </div>
```

Comment: Did you tried replacing `'category_name' => 'Art' , 'Technology', 'Fashion-Beauty')` (which is not valid anyway) by `'category' => id_of_the_category`?

Comment: The WP Codex seems to think category_name is ok. But I shall try category ID instead. Thanks :)

Comment: It should be an array of category slugs (`'category_name' => array('art', 'technology', 'fashion-beauty')`, you were not creating one.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the `category` in an array of `category IDs` seemed to fix the situation.

I used the following code:

`<?php $the_query6 = new WP_Query(array('category__in' => array( 240, 243, 239, ),'posts_per_page' => 4)); ?>`

Comment: Improved your answer by keeping the categories slugs instead of using the numeric identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit line is the following:

```
<?php $the_query6 = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page' => 6, 
    'category_name' => 'Art', 
    'Technology', 
    'Fashion-Beauty')
); ?>
```

To extract the posts belonging to different categories, the following format must be used ([read more about it on WordPress' documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters)) :

- Posts in one of the categories: `'category_name' => 'art,technology,fashion-beauty'`
- Posts in both categories: `'category_name' => 'art+technology+fashion-beauty'`